# rosdep initialisation error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've tried both today and yesterday incase it was a temporary thing, however I constantly recieve this error when trying to initialise rosdep:

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

The other solutions I've seen assume that it's a proxy that is causing this but I am not using a proxy and I am able to ping github successfully as well as view the actual link it returns. I apologise if I have missed something simple here but I've been banging my head trying everything so far. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and using the Indigo Igloo version of ROS and my rosdep version is 0.10.30. If there is any further information you need just let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193466/rosdep-initialisation-error/) by [Aracanid](https://answers.ros.org/users/20303/aracanid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm adding this edit in case others run into similar problems. The entire root of my problem seems to have been Virgin Media. Although it doesn't come up when you check for proxies or IP filtering, they do employ something in the background to filter for DMCA infringing sites so that they can block them. When I tethered my PC to my phone and used my phones data to initialise and update rosdep everything worked perfectly first time around.

Not sure if this will help everyone who had this problem but hopefully it does.

/////
*Manually adding the files has thankfully fixed this but I now get this error:
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
ERROR: unable to process source [https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
<urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol> (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)
Anyone got any ideas?*
////

---

Originally posted by [Aracanid](https://answers.ros.org/users/20303/aracanid/) with karma: 51 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-26**:
You need to change the contents of the sources list to point to your local copies not the ones on the web.

**Comment by [joe930](https://answers.ros.org/users/28258/joe930/) on 2016-10-15**:
Thank you this worked for me!